# getting a refused connection error when trying to do HTTP->HTTPS in lighttpd.config

Tags: http, https, lighttpd

I was looking at how to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the Lighttpd website, and it looked really easy.  (https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps)

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  # capture vhost name with regex conditiona -> %0 in redirect pattern
  # must be the most inner block to the redirect rule
  $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
    url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
  }
}
```

but it doesn't reroute at all.

I have been trying to access the websites by way of *www.test.com*, *http://www.test.com*, and *http://test.com* but it doesnt seem to work.

It just says:  ERR Connection Refused.  I have confirmed that the website works in http and https without this code, but when doing this, it doesnt seem to work.

I would like to understand it more since I will have a bunch of other domains routing through here eventually.

I have also tried more specific calls as well which didnt work:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  # capture vhost name with regex conditiona -> %0 in redirect pattern
  # must be the most inner block to the redirect rule
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "www.test.com" {
    url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
  }
}
```

Comment: It is likely that you have neglected to clear your browser cache, or you have neglected to restart lighttpd after making configuration changes, or the lighttpd you are running is not using the configuration file you have been editing, or "mod_redirect" is not listed in server.modules in your lighttpd config.

Comment: A) cleared. B) always run `init.d/lighttpd restart` C) Confirmed config file since i can jump between port 80 and 443 for the server,  Not sure what mod redirect is though and how to confirm it in my module.  I dont mind lighttpd, i just need to make sure i understand it more.  Right now I have 1 config file working 6 different webservers, based on the accessing domain.... but that is a different story.

Comment: Run `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p` and substitute the path to your config file, if different.  See if `server.modules` contains mod_redirect.  You should also check error.log to see if there is useful information there.

Comment: ill check those and get back to you.

Comment: @gstrauss When I looked at modules.conf, i noticed that mod_redirect was not enabled.  I reenabled it, then restarted the server.  Now the forwarding works! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the above code in the question is actually valid.  The issue is, as pointed out by @Gstrauss is that in order to have redirect capabilities, you need to make sure that module is actually enabled.  I looked into the modules.conf file and noticed it was not enabled.

Upon enabling the *mod_redirect*, and restarting the server, no matter if i went to HTTP or HTTPS version of my site, it would forward me to the HTTPS version of the site.